# Is it possible to draw a path of coordinates and navigate between them, using Google Maps or other apps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is a simple question.

I know it's possible to request to navigate to a specific place, as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44945367/878126).

I know there are also some other APIs for Google Maps ([**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) and [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)), but I don't see an option to send multiple coordinates, to see the path between them, and navigate between them.

For the Web version, there is the ability for waypoints (example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15406847/878126) and [**here**](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)), but not for Android.

Is it possible to do it, via Google Maps, or another app?

Or maybe even in the Google Maps API (within the current app) ?

Comment: Just in case it doesn't exist, I've written a request about it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70311419

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since V3 [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) support up to 23 [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) (excluding the origin and destination) when calculating routes:

> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=sydney,au&destination=perth,au&waypoints=via:-37.81223%2C144.96254%7Cvia:-34.92788%2C138.60008&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

So, you can draw polyline with up to 23 points and send they coords in request.

UPDATE:
Please see [this](http://www.akexorcist.com/2015/12/google-direction-library-for-android-en.html) tutorial.

UPDATE 2:

Example opening navigation mode of Google Maps app for route Tel-Aviv to Jerusalem via Kiryat Malakhi, Beit+Guvrin and geopoint (31.696342, 35.011337) via `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&" +
                                "origin=3780+St+1,+Tel-Aviv+Yafo,+Israel&destination=Jerusalem,+Israel&travelmode=driving" +
                                "&waypoints=Kiryat+Malakhi,+Israel%7CBeit+Guvrin,+Israel%7C31.696342, 35.011337"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Result:

[image: Waypoints for Google Maps App example]

Parameter details [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action).

Comment: The question is about Google Maps API. Not the one of the web. Will it work with it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Why not? You just need to send request and process result in your application. Like, for example, for Static Maps API.

Comment: Will it work including not just showing the path, but also allow to navigate through all of the locations that I've specified? Will it allow to do it all in the Google Maps app? Or is it only used in the current app ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes (see [this article](https://www.codevog.com/de/blog/2015-04-20-google-direction-api-for-android) as example), you can process API response  in your application as you wish. But you should implement getting current location, showing it on map etc. in your application.

Comment: Google Maps URLs that were mentioned in the question also support waypoints. So you can generate a URL with waypoints and use it in the intent to open navigation mode of Google Maps app: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Comment: So do I use an intent for showing this URL, and it will open Google Maps app with all the waypoints, the whole path, and allow to navigate through them all?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm prefer Google Maps API, but, as [xomena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5140781/xomena) wrote in his comment above - yes.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko I'm talking about what the answer has in the code. I just use the intent of showing the URL he created, and that's it?

Comment: Is this API also somehow available for other popular apps, such as Waze?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Please see update 2 for answer. I don't know. I'm not working with Waze API. IMHO should be - it's common functionality.

Comment: @androiddeveloper But seems there is [no such possibility](https://wiki.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=53556&start=40) in Waze

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Say, how come the feature of multiple points isn't available for end users on the app? Or is it? And how did you know in which country I live?

Comment: @androiddeveloper You mean end users of Google Maps App? Seems it's [available](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-add-multiple-destinations-google-maps).